# Sybase null datetime

Tags: datetime, null, sybase, sap-ase

I am attempting to insert a row into a table while leaving two datetime columns null.

Error (for both columns):

> The column column_name in table conflict does not allow null values.

The only constraint the table table has is a primary key constraint. The constraint is not on the datetime columns.

Is it possible to have a null datetime in Sybase?

Comment: Please share your table definition code

Comment: can you share the table script and insert script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize that Sybase defaulted columns to not null. I need to set the columns as null.

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting the NULL value as a datetime datatype and see if that works.

For example:

`INSERT INTO tbl_conflict (date_column) VALUES (CAST(NULL AS datetime))`